# How apply more complex operations on every element of a list?

Tags: haskell

I need to apply a operation on each element of a list. The operation is "y = (3*x) rem 16". In this case I (think I) can't use the map function.

Ex:

```
x = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6]

y = [0 3 6 9 12 15 2]
```

I am new in funcional programming, especially haskell, so i'm having some trouble with that.

Thanks

Comment: *Why* do you think you can't use `map`?

Answer (score 4):

You can definitely use `map`, you just need to define the function you want to map over the list.

```
fancypants x = (3*x) `rem` 16

ghci> map fancypants [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehensions:

```
[(3 * x) `rem` 16 | x <- data_source]
```

You can also try this, although it may seem not so readable, but it involves `map`:

```
map ((flip rem) 16) $ map (3*) data_source
```

---

Here's how it works:

- `map (3*) data_source` multiplies each element of `data_source` by 3, pretty straightforward
- `map ((flip rem) 16) $ stuff` applies the function `((flip rem) 16)` to each element of `stuff`

  - `(flip rem) 16` is a function of one argument `x` that computes the value of `rem x 16`

Now, you could've used `rem 16` instead of that `flip`ping business, but in that case the function'll return `rem 16 x` instead, which isn't what you want.

---

You can also use this, which looks a bit cleaner than the second version:

```
map (((flip rem) 16) . (3*)) data_source
```

The dot (`.`), as in `function1 . function2` creates a composite function which works like the following: `function1 $ function2 x`.

Comment: Do consider the level of the students you are answering.  It seems this student has never even seen a lambda; this is a pretty advanced answer considering. (composition, HOFs, sections...)

Comment: @luqui, I tried to start with the simplest example and then moved to something a bit more complicated, _while explaining how that code works_. BTW, thanks for calling my answer 'pretty advanced' as I just started learning Haskell about a month ago :D Looks like I'm doing not terribly bad.

Comment: The list-comprehension solution is perfectly readable and lovely. The point-free thing is "advanced" in that it shows you have some mastery of a useful technique, but it is probably best not applied here.